# Listing email addresses on web pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to colour and change the font size through css but its not working.  Below is what I written but its not working and I don't know what the problem is.  Any ideas would be welcome?

javascript

```
<script>
emailA = 'thestation.com'
emailA = ('jason' + '@' + emailA)
document.write('<a href="mailto:' + emailA +'">' + emailA +'</a>')
</script>
<br>

<script>
emailB = 'thestation.com'
emailB = ('arnold' + '@' + emailB)
document.write('<a href="mailto:' + emailB +'">' + emailB +'</a>')
</script>
<br>

<script>
emailC = 'thestation.com'
emailC = ('vincent' + '@' + emailC)
document.write('<a href="mailto:' + emailC +'">' + emailC +'</a>')
</script>
<br>

<script>
emailD = 'thestation.com'
emailD = ('paul' + '@' + emailD)
document.write('<a href="mailto:' + emailD +'">' + emailD +'</a>')
</script>
```

CSS

```
.emailA {
font-size: 2em;
color: green;
}
.emailB {
font-size: 3em;
colour: green;
}
.emailC {
font-size: 4em;
colour: green;
}
.emailD {
font-size: 5em;
colour: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="emailA"></div>
<div class="emailB"></div>
<div class="emailC"></div>
<div class="emailD"></div>
```

Comment: You're styling the `<div>` that contains a `<a>` link element, which requires its own styling. so address them using `.emailC a { /* the code */ }`

Comment: `document.write()` doesn't write into those DIVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using the divs in your HTML at all. Try adding the class in each a element like so

```
document.write('<a href="mailto:' + emailA +'" class="emailA">' + emailA +'</a>')
```

and you will see the links styled correctly.

Comment: and give the link a display:block to mimic the block aspect of the div

Answer (score 0):

It should be color, not colour, in the css notation.
One way to format ist to use the class attribute inside the a tag, see emailA.
To place the anchor inside a div the css must be rewritten to affect the anchor (.emailB a).
To avoid confusion handling different div when injecting the anchor inside a unique id may help (emailC).
When injecting the anchor inside the div the injecting code must be executed after the div is rendered (emailB, emailC).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Color email address</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .emailA {
            font-size: 2em;
            color: green;
        }
        .emailB a {
            font-size: 3em;
            color: red;
        }
        .emailC a {
            font-size: 4em;
            color: magenta;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        emailA = 'thestation.com'
        emailA = ('jason' + '@' + emailA)
        document.write('<a class="emailA" href="mailto:' + emailA + '">' + emailA + '</a>')
    </script>
    <div class="emailB"></div>
    <script>
        emailB = 'thestation.com'
        emailB = ('arnold' + '@' + emailB)
        document.getElementsByClassName("emailB").item(0).innerHTML = '<a href="mailto:' + emailB + '">' + emailB + '</a>'
    </script>
    <div class="emailC" id="emailCId"></div>
    <script>
        emailC = 'thestation.com'
        emailC = ('vincent' + '@' + emailC)
        document.getElementById("emailCId").innerHTML = '<a href="mailto:' + emailC + '">' + emailC + '</a>'
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```